# Getting a navbar to work in React. Sending a function to a child through props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have the following code in my App component. Rather that having the Navbar nested in my App component directly is there a way to have a separate navbar.js file with with the Navbar component that is passed the "setshow()" function through props. Then through the onClick can still change what is rendered in "show" the Parent App function.

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home'
import Selfdev from './components/Selfdev'
import Webdev from './components/Webdev'


function App() {


  const [show,setshow] = useState(<Home/>)

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div id="Navbar" className="">
      <div onClick={() => setshow(<Home/>)} className="cursor-pointer">Home</div>
      <div onClick={() => setshow(<Webdev/>)} className="cursor-pointer">Webdev</div>
      <div onClick={() => setshow(<Selfdev/>)}>Selfdev</div>
    </div>
    {show} 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Instead of saving a component to the state you could create variables that check if `Home`, `Webdev`, etc... need to be shown. Based on these boolean values you can conditionally render these components. But honestly seems to me you need a routing solution like react-router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have something like this:

```
 const Navbar = ({ setshow }) => (
  <div id="Navbar" className="">
    <div onClick={() => setshow(<Home />)} className="cursor-pointer">
      Home
    </div>
    <div onClick={() => setshow(<Webdev />)} className="cursor-pointer">
      Webdev
    </div>
    <div onClick={() => setshow(<Selfdev />)}>Selfdev</div>
  </div>
)

function App() {
  const [show, setshow] = useState(<Home />)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar setshow={setshow} />
      {show}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am not sure if your question is based on different Navbar semantics, or are you just interested in passing the props to the Navbar component like in the example above?

In order to separate the Navbar into its own file, do the following:

Create `Navbar.js`:

```
import React from 'react'

import Home from './components/Home'
import Selfdev from './components/Selfdev'
import Webdev from './components/Webdev'

const Navbar = ({ setshow }) => (
  <div id="Navbar" className="">
    <div onClick={() => setshow(<Home />)} className="cursor-pointer">
      Home
    </div>
    <div onClick={() => setshow(<Webdev />)} className="cursor-pointer">
      Webdev
    </div>
    <div onClick={() => setshow(<Selfdev />)}>Selfdev</div>
  </div>
)

export default Navbar
```

And then modify your Main file like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import Navbar from './Navbar'
import Home from './components/Home'

function App() {
  const [show, setshow] = useState(<Home />)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar setshow={setshow} />
      {show}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

also, in JS it is prefered to use `camelCase`, so instead of `setshow` you would have `setShow` - just a tip.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the use of camelCase. I wanted to see if could have the Navbar function in it's own Navbar.js file. Is it possible to still make it workable from a separate file?

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem solved. It was driving me crazy.